# how to set sbt plugins invoke scope?

Tags: sbt

```
val webAssemblyTask = TaskKey[Unit](
  "web-assembly",
  "assembly web/war like run-time package"
)

var out: TaskStreams = _

val baseSettings: Seq[Setting[_]] = Seq(
    webAssemblyOutputDir <<= (sourceManaged) { _ / "build" },
    webAssemblyTask <<= (
    streams,
    target,
    sourceDirectory,
    outputDirProjectName
) map {
  (out_log, targetDir, sourceDir, outputDirProjectName) => {
      out_log.log.info("web-assembly start")
      out_log.log.info("sourceDir:" + sourceDir.getAbsolutePath)
      out_log.log.info("targetDir:" + targetDir.getAbsolutePath)
      val sourceAssetsDir = (sourceDir / "webapp" / "assets").toPath
      val classesAssetsDir = (targetDir / "scala-2.10" / "classes" / "assets").toPath
      Files.createSymbolicLink(classesAssetsDir, sourceAssetsDir)
    }
  }
)

val webAssemblySettings = inConfig(Runtime)(baseSettings)
```

I wrote a plugin of sbt.
I type webAssembly in sbt console, the plugin run ok.
But I want to run after compile, before runtime, how can I do it？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### how to set sbt plugins invoke scope?

I think you're confusing the configuration (also known as Maven scope) name with tasks like `compile` and `run`. They happen to have related configuration, but that doesn't mean `compile` task is identical to `Compile` configuration.

I could interpret this question to be how can a plugin setting invoke tasks scoped in some other configuration. For that you use `in` method like: `key in (Config)` or `key in (Config, task)`. Another way to interpret it may be how can plugin tasks be scoped in a configuration. You use `inConfig(Config)(...)`, which you're already doing. But you'd typically want plugins to be configuration neutral. See [my blog post](http://eed3si9n.com/4th-dimension-with-sbt-013) for more details on this.

### I want to run after compile, before run, how can I do it？

This makes much more sense. In sbt you mostly focus on the preconditions of the tasks. One of the useful command is `inspect tree key`. You can run that for `run` tasks and get the entire tasks/settings that it depends on. Here's where you see it calling `compile:compile` (another notation for `compile in Compile`):

```
helloworld> inspect tree run
[info] compile:run = InputTask[Unit]
[info]   +-runtime:fullClasspath = Task[scala.collection.Seq[sbt.Attributed[java.io.File]]]
[info]   | +-runtime:exportedProducts = Task[scala.collection.Seq[sbt.Attributed[java.io.File]]]
[info]   | | +-compile:packageBin::artifact = Artifact(sbt-sequential,jar,jar,None,List(compile),None,Map())
[info]   | | +-runtime:configuration = runtime
[info]   | | +-runtime:products = Task[scala.collection.Seq[java.io.File]]
[info]   | | | +-compile:classDirectory = target/scala-2.10/sbt-0.13/classes
[info]   | | | +-compile:copyResources = Task[scala.collection.Seq[scala.Tuple2[java.io.File, java.io.File]]]
[info]   | | | +-compile:compile = Task[sbt.inc.Analysis]
```

This is useful in discovering `compile:products`, which "Build products that get packaged" according to `help products` command:

```
helloworld> help products
Build products that get packaged.
```

Since `runtime:products` happens before `compile:run`, if it depended on your task, your task will be called before `compile:run` (`inspect tree` also shows that `run` resolved to that).

To simplify your plugin task, I'm just going to call it `sayHello`:

```
val sayHello = taskKey[Unit]("something")

sayHello := {
  println("hello")
}
```

You can rewire `products in Runtime` as follows:

```
products in Runtime := {
  val old = (products in Runtime).value
  sayHello.value
  old
}
```

This will satisfy "before run" part. You want to make sure that this runs after `compile`. Again, just add task dependency to it:

```
sayHello := {
  (compile in Compile).value  
  println("hello")
}
```

When the user runs `run` task, sbt will correct calculate the dependencies and runs `sayHello` task somewhere between `compile` and `run`.